# ASP.NET 6 Web API with Docker default project does not work

Tags: asp.net, docker

When I generate a ASP.NET 6 Web API project with Docker enabled (WeatherForecast API) I cannot make requests to it.

The project does start and there are no errors/warnings inside the Docker logs. Starting the project without Docker works perfectly fine. All I did was generate the project and start it, nothing changed.

The built-in Swagger page, which opens on start up, can't be reached either. I checked and the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to Development, so that's not it.

Requests with the browser or Postman do not work.

Is this normal behavior and I have to change some settings inside the Dockerfile maybe? What am I missing?

Edit:

Was able to get it to run by writing the Dockerfile manually, although I'm still wondering why the auto-generated Dockerfile does not work out of the box...

Comment: How do you run the container? Do you map port 80 to a free port on the host and access it through that?

Comment: I run it in Debug mode, through VS. As far as I can tell, the ports are automatically assigned. If I inspect the container it says: 80/tcp - 0.0.0.0:49178